# Node js app is failed to upload to azure service

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to upload my node app to azure app services,
The app is an express app that runs on port 8080 and listening for post requests
when deploying it with vscode it keeps failing with the following log:

```
    4:41:38: Using existing resource group "appsvc_linux_centralus".
14:41:39: Ensuring App Service plan "appsvc_linux_centralus" exists...
14:41:39: Creating App Service plan "appsvc_linux_centralus"...
14:42:10: Successfully created App Service plan "appsvc_linux_centralus".
14:42:10: Verifying that Application Insights is available for this location...
14:42:12: Creating Application Insights resource "orizvibot"...
14:42:20: Successfully created Application Insights resource "orizvibot".
14:42:20: Creating new web app "orizvibot"...
14:42:43: Created new web app "orizvibot": https://orizvibot.azurewebsites.net
14:42:47 orizvibot: Starting deployment...
14:42:49 orizvibot: Creating zip package...
14:43:26 orizvibot: Fetching changes.
14:43:27 orizvibot: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/cd7130ae-4472-4659-9719-6ca6b3f41a4e.zip (0.02 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
14:43:33 orizvibot: Updating submodules.
14:43:34 orizvibot: Preparing deployment for commit id '47824e40-c'.
14:43:34 orizvibot: Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
14:43:34 orizvibot: Running oryx build...
14:43:34 orizvibot: Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform nodejs --platform-version 14 -i /tmp/8d907df5b84c97b -p compress_node_modules=tar-gz --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log 
14:43:39 orizvibot: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
14:43:39 orizvibot: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
14:43:39 orizvibot: Oryx Version: 0.2.20210225.2, Commit: f7b557f29a83aa078cc94c0056e7337c07f14271, ReleaseTagName: 20210225.2
14:43:39 orizvibot: Build Operation ID: |/lykwYbLGE4=.808061dd_
14:43:39 orizvibot: Repository Commit : 47824e40-c8bb-4824-8fbb-f1aeeab1af0b
14:43:39 orizvibot: Detecting platforms...
14:43:42 orizvibot: Detected following platforms:
14:43:42 orizvibot:   nodejs: 14.15.1
14:43:42 orizvibot: Version '14.15.1' of platform 'nodejs' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
14:43:42 orizvibot: Error: Oops... An unexpected error has occurred.
14:43:44 orizvibot: /opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform nodejs --platform-version 14 -i /tmp/8d907df5b84c97b -p compress_node_modules=tar-gz --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log 
14:44:03 orizvibot: Deployment failed.
```

Any help?
I can figure out what the issue is..

Comment: Have you checked this file(/tmp/build-debug.log) to know why it's failing? Locate the log file(/tmp/build-debug.log) in your system. The output is what is needed to help you figure out what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs is not getting installed in your server, check the scripts and deploy again

Comment: For some reason i dont have the log file.. not even the tmp folder.

Comment: its hidden, use something to see that